# Custom UIViewController transition bug in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

I encountered a strange bug. I am just using iOS's custom transitioning method for `UIViewControllers` using `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` together with an implementation of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. It all seems to work fine, until I do exactly the following:

1. open the app
2. present another view controller with my custom transition
3. rotate to landscape
4. dismiss the just presented view controller

That's all! What happens now is the following: I see a large black bar on the right side of the initial view controller (as if that controller's view wasn't rotated to landscape).

The funny thing is this only goes wrong in iOS 9, in iOS 8 everything seems to work just fine. Did anything change with custom transition API I don't know of? Or is this simply a really nasty iOS 9 bug? If anyone can tell me what I did wrong or if anyone can provide me with a workaround I would really appreciate that!

These classes reproduce the problem:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func tap() {
        let controller = ModalViewController()
        controller.transitioningDelegate = self
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController,
                                                   presentingController presenting: UIViewController,
                                                   sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return Transitioning()
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return Transitioning()
    }
}
```

The presented view controller:

```
import UIKit
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func tap() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And finally the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` implementation:

```
import UIKit
class Transitioning: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
        if let fromView = fromView, toView = toView {
            containerView?.addSubview(fromView)
            containerView?.addSubview(toView)

            toView.alpha = 0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                toView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: {
                finished in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I played around with this some more and I found a 'fix' but this is a dirty workaround of course. If I add this line right before the animation starts: `toView.frame = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].bounds` the problem disappears. So the clue I take from this is: the frame of the main ViewController is not updated after rotating the ModalViewController. So weird.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this question please explain what I could do to make this question better? I am a bit puzzled why it was downvoted.

Comment: Personally, I generally use `toView.frame = fromView.frame`, but your approach may be fine for your needs. FYI, you don't have to add `fromView` to the hierarchy, as it's already there. Re downvote, I don't know as it seems like a legitimate question ... I didn't search, but perhaps this has been asked before. I agree, though, that it's tiresome when people don't say why they downvoted.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob! That is a much nicer solution, also you're totally right for not having to add the fromView to the container. Can you please put your answer in an actual answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The issue you commented seems to have been reported here http://www.splinter.com.au/2015/04/17/ios8-view-controller-transitioning-bug/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use the following in `animateTransition`:

```
toView.frame = fromView.frame
```

FYI, you don't have to add `fromView` to the hierarchy, as it's already there.